# how to get an attribute value that returns a boolean in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, attributes

```
<h1 class="style-scope group-search" data-group-search="false" style="display: none;">Searching...</h1>
```

I need to get the value that changes from false to true using selenium-java, so I can create a preconditionWait that waits for the value to return true, in order to continue with the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to get a working solution for you with the lack of HTML and context, but here's my best..

```
bool groupSearch = false;
while (!groupSearch)
    groupSearch = Boolean.parse(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".style-scope.group-search")).getAttribute("data-group-search"));

// at this point in the code, the `data-group-search` will be `true`
```

Comment: your solution gave me a good idea. I ended up using the boolean and waiting until it changed to false (initial condition== true), and add my own precondition wait. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While searching for the text, that boolean may changes. So you can get the boolean value of the web element using getAttribute() method.

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1[contains(text(),'Searching')]"));
 boolean isSearch = element.getAttribute("data-group-search");
```